# React Native with Google OpenID Connect

Tags: react-native, authentication, jwt, google-oauth, openid-connect

I am working on a react native application and I have some problems with OpenID connect. I would like to use some "Login with Google" functionality.

In normal (not native) react app I use the react-google-login library like this:

```
    import { GoogleLogin} from 'react-google-login';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    
    const Login = () => {
        const loginHandler = (response) => {
            // I can use the OpenID JWT token got as response.tokenId e.g.
            axios.get("/myapi", {
              headers: {
                  Authorization: 'Bearer ' + response.tokenId
              }
            }).then(res => {
              ...
            });
        }
    
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                    <GoogleLogin
                        clientId={CLIENT_ID}
                        buttonText='Login'
                        onSuccess={loginHandler}
                        cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
                        responseType='code,token'
                        uxMode="redirect"
                    />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
    
    export default Login;
```

In the login handler as you can see I can use the OpenID JWT token and I can send it to the server.

I need the same in React Native but I haven't found any simple library for that. Neither of them returns the OpenID JWT token just the Oauth2 access token.

Does anybody have any idea which library I should use and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use this library

```
npm install react-native-app-auth --savereact-native link react-native-app-auth
```

If you use yarn as a packet manager

```
yarn add @react-native-app-auth
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, it would be nice to use some expo API. I have found the [Google API](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/google/) but it only returns the standard Oauth2 access token but not the OpenID connect JWT token. The other is [GoogleSignIn](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/google-sign-in/) but it has other limitations described here https://forums.expo.io/t/could-not-sign-in-google-with-expo-sdk-33/29418 But in the end it seems that I have to use a non-expo library. E.g. the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to accomplish this with [AppAuth](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/app-auth/)